# Math in JavaBean

Tags: java, math

I have tried a few different ways to write this problem out and I keep on having issues. So I have 5 categories that need to be averaged out. Here is just a sample code of one part of the code:

```
public double getAvg()    {
String[] Avg = new String[]{Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4};  
int sum = 0;
for (String input : Avg)       {
sum += Integer.parseInt(input);   
                                                }
                    return sum * (10);
                                        }
```

So there are 4 other similar sections like this. Anyway, I need to take these 5 results and have them post a total using this equation:

```
(((part1)*(.35))+((part2)*(.15))+((part3)*(.10))+((part4)+(.20))+((part5)*(.20)))=100%
```

-

So, I need to clarify. I am writing a javabean that gets and overall average of statistics input by the user. There are 5 sections that need to be evaluated to get an overall average of the given statistics. I have written three convenience methods to get the first three averages(one of these is what is shown above in the example code). The last 2 values are input by the user.

So what I need is to write a convenience method in the bean that gets the averages in the manner shown above and takes the two additional values input by the user and then spits out an overall average using this rubric:

Value A: 35% of overall average

Value B: 15% of overall average

Value C: 10% of overall average

Value D: 20% of overall average

Value E: 20% of overall average.

The trouble that I am having is I don't know how to factor in the answers of the three convenience methods into the overall average convenience method.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the question how to convert each Q1 into a `double`, or how to execute that expression, or ... ?

Comment: An average is calculated by summing N items and dividing by N.  (Primary school maths ...)

Comment: @StephenC It would appear from the last line of the question that he wants a weighted average.  However, he's not likely to get a satisfactory answer while the question is so vague.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a weighted average. I know enough to find the values that comprise the 5 sections that make up the total but I don't know how to get it in code. Basically, I can write the javabean and the jsp to take in the individual values for each section but I don't know how to get the weighted average of each section in java. Sorry, I'm still learning.